# Как работает Varargs с коллекциями?

Tags: java, коллекции, generics, varargs

Недавно наткнулся на такой пример :

```
class Test {
    static void say(Set<Double>... set) { 
    }
}
```

На сколько я знаю, Varargs создает массив из переданных аргументов, а массивы generic создавать нельзя.

```
Set<Double>[] setOfDoubles= new HashSet<Double>[2];  // ошибка компиляции
```

Каким образом создается массив коллекции с generic в данном случае?

Comment: [Potential Vulnerabilities of Varargs Methods with Non-Reifiable Formal Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<Double>[] setOfDoubles = (Set<Double>[]) new HashSet[2];
```

или

```
Set<Double>[] setOfDoubles = new HashSet[2];
```

а потом при использовании приводить тип